# debug a project with references in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, project

I have two separete c# projects. One is a helper library that is included as a reference to another main project. The main project solution only has a reference to the helper library and not the entire source code there. I want to run the main project but also want to be able to debug and step through the code in the helper code. How can I do that? I have the source code for both projects.

Comment: yes. The helper dll is referenced.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you **compile the library on your machine** and include the .PDB files your visual studio should be able to step into the code if you use the `Step In` command while debugging.

If you want to breakpoint in that code, file->open then select the .cs file from the other project and set a breakpoint.

Hover your mouse over the breakpoint and it'll say something like:

`At Something.cs, line 12 character 34 ('MyOtherLibrary')`

This means the debugger is attached to the code in your helper library.

Answer (score 3):

2 more things:

- make sure PDB is loaded for the DLL you are adding. Check if in the "Debug -> Windows -> Modules" window the DLL in question have PDB from the correct path. If not you can force VS to load PDB by right click -> load symbols on the module in the same window.
- if everything else fails try to turn off "my code only" in Tools -> Options -> Debugging. This will make VS to try load PDBs for all Dlls and allow breaking on throw for every exception.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to add the helper project to the main solution, rather than using a reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you have source code then instead of adding this helper library as DLL reference, you can add the whole source code to main solution (add->existing project) and then reference the helper project instead of DLL (delete the DLL reference prior to adding project reference),

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of below:

- Create a solution and add helper library to it. Debugging is easy
- Build helper project as a debug DLL **on your machine** and you should be able to step through it. You can also load files you want to debug by File->Open file

Answer (score 0):

what helped me is:
right click on project sln,
-> then select properties
-> then go to services and check there "Enable client application services"