# How to step into function to debug code in C# unit test?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am trying to add a C# unit test (.net 4.5) to an existing solution that creates an instance of a class and calls a public method, and it will execute the code but not let me step into it. The code is in another project in the solution and I've written unit tests before that let me step into code. The assembly from the main project (that houses the code I want to step into) is in my GAC, but I added it to the unit test project as a project reference, not assembly reference.

Code in the test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CalculateChartlines_HasValidCL()
{
    //populating lvi, startDate, endDate
    ChartLines pchart = new ChartLines();
      
    CenterlineDateRange cdr = new CenterlineDateRange(0, true, startDate, endDate, 12);           

    var valuesOut = pchart.CalculateChartLines(ChartType.P_Chart, lvi, cdr); //steps over
    ...
}
```

ChartLines class in another project in the same solution (I added this project as a reference):

```
public class ChartLines : ILNCharts
{
    public ChartLines()
    { 
    
    }
    public List<ValuesOut> CalculateChartLines(ChartType chartType, List<ValuesIn> lvi, CenterlineDateRange cldr)
    {
        return GetCalculateChartLines(chartType, lvi, cldr);
    }
    ...
}

public interface ILNCharts
{
    List<ValuesOut> CalculateChartLines(ChartType chartType, List<ValuesIn> lvi, CenterlineDateRange cldr);
    <other methods>
}
```

Comment: If the assembly exists in the GAC with the same name and version number, it will use the GAC copy instead of your local project.  If you want it to load the version you're compiling, you need to rename the assembly or change its version number, or remove the copy from the GAC.

Comment: Ugh that's annoying. I deleted it out the GAC entirely and then re-added the reference and now it's working. Visual Studio is trying to be too smart. You should add this as an answer if you want credit

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to add the dll from the project after building it in debug mode and then add the reference to your test project, i do that in my projects.

Maybe this would help too: [debug a project with references in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557942/debug-a-project-with-references-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did just that. But it's working now- solution was to use a different version number or delete it out of the GAC